# ReactJS - Issues about Dynamic Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have these components. I want to turn every  into a dynamic url. For example, when accessing in the browser, `http://localhost:3000/houses/1` I want to appear the House 1.

The other things in the application are working fine. I just want to solve this problem of implementing dynamic routes.

The data is fetched from a json file

**db.json file**

```
[
  {
    "houseId": 1,
    "name": "House 1",
    "photos": [
      "house1_001.jpg",
      "house1_002.jpg",
      "house1_003.jpg",
      "house1_004.jpg"
    ]
  },
  {
    "houseId": 2,
    "name": "House 2",
    "photos": [
      "house2_001.jpg",
      "house2_002.jpg",
      "house2_003.jpg",
      "house2_004.jpg"      
    ]
  },
  {
    "houseId": 3,
    "name": "House 3",
    "photos": [
      "house3_001.jpg",
      "house3_002.jpg",
      "house3_003.jpg",
      "house3_004.jpg"     
    ]
  } 
]
```

**Router Component**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

    import App from './App'
    import Intro from './Intro'
    import Houses from './Houses'
    import House from './House'


    export default props => (
      <Router>
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => <App />} >
          <Route exact path='/intro' render={() => <Intro />} />
          <Route exact path='/houses' render={() => <Houses />} />
          <Route exact path='/houses/:houseId' render={(props) => <House {...props} />} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    )
```

**Houses Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import House from './House'

var data = require('./db.json');

class Houses extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      houses: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      houses: data
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { houses } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="content house">
        {
          houses.map((house, index) => {
            return (
              <div>            
                <House house={house} />
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Houses


**House Component**

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class House extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    houseId: ""
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      houseId: this.props.match.params.id
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.props.house.name}</h3>
        <ul>
          {this.props.house.photos.map((photo, index) => {
            return (
              <li><img src={`/images/${photo}`} /></li>
            )
          })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default House;
```

**House component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class House extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    houseId: ""
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      houseId: this.props.match.params.id
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.props.house.name}</h3>
        <ul>
          {this.props.house.photos.map((photo, index) => {
            return (
              <li><img src={`/images/${photo}`} /></li>
            )
          })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default House;
```

Comment: Hi. What's the problem you are getting? Any traceback? A description of the behavior? What's the `House` component?

Comment: I edited my question. I was forgotten to include the House component. I inserted it now.

Comment: pass the houses data to `<House />` and use id to display the correct house data.

Comment: Can you explain me it more detailed? just showing it in the code?

Comment: @claudiobitar I've added an answer

Comment: I will try to implement your solution if it will be successfully I will upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the json data to `<House/>` component and use the id to display the correct data.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const data = require('./db.json');

class House extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      houses: data,
    }
  }

  render() {

    const houseId = this.props.match.params.houseId;

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.state.houses[houseId].name}</h3>
        <ul>
          {this.state.houses[houseId].photos.map((photo, index) => {
            return (
              <li><img src={`/images/${photo}`} /></li>
            )
          })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default House;
```

Create two components, one will be rendered in Houses and one will be render on `house/1`

```
 // rendered inside Houses
 class House extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.props.house.name}</h3>
        <ul>
          {this.props.house.photos.map((photo, index) => {
            return (
              <li><img src={`/images/${photo}`} /></li>
            )
          })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

HouseInfo, which display data by query parameter

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const data = require('./db.json');

class HouseInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      houses: data,
    }
  }

  render() {

    const id = this.props.match.params.houseId;
    const houseId = id >= 1 ? id - 1 : 0; 

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.state.houses[houseId].name}</h3>
        <ul>
          {this.state.houses[houseId].photos.map((photo, index) => {
            return (
              <li><img src={`/images/${photo}`} /></li>
            )
          })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default HouseInfo;
```

Router

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

import App from './App'
import Intro from './Intro'
import Houses from './Houses'
import House from './House'
import HouseInfo from './HouseInfo'


export default props => (
  <Router>
    <Route exact path='/' render={() => <App />} >
      <Route exact path='/intro' render={() => <Intro />} />
      <Route exact path='/houses' render={() => <Houses />} />
      <Route exact path='/houses/:houseId' render={(props) => <HouseInfo {...props} />} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
)
```

Comment: It didn't work. There is an error message:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
pointed to this code line:
`const houseId = this.props.match.params.houseId;`

Comment: it won't work because you are using the component in Houses and also in your routes as a standard alone component.

Comment: I'll add an example

Comment: I'm waiting for your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195628/discussion-between-junius-l-and-claudiobitar).

Answer (score 0):

Entire snippet is right except the thing is that you have wrongly matched the **params** id,
change the following code in house component

```
this.setState({
  houseId: this.props.match.params.houseId
})
```

you have to use the same param id ie.,**houseId** inside the component

using the houseId in the state ie.,(this.state.houseId) in House component, loop through the json data and find the houseId and display the corresponding data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what props you are passing to the House component but my guess is not exactly intended ones. Try this:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
...
export default withRouter(Houses);
```

or without withRouter:

```
  <Route exact path='/houses/:houseId' render={House} />
```

and in your Route your param value is specified as houseId, as it should be in House component:

```
this.setState({
  houseId: this.props.match.params.houseId
})
```